# Deriving the two-point function in CFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I am trying to understand the textbook derivation of the two-point function in CFT as spelled out in [this CFT book by Francesco](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9). The same derivation can also be found in [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176664/).

However, I don't understand the final step they do in their approach.

So the derivation goes something like this:

Consider two primary fields $\phi_1(x_1)$ and $\phi_2(x_2)$. Since we know how the primary fields transform we can write their two-point function as

\begin{equation}
\langle\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\rangle =\left|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\right|^{\Delta_1/d}_{x=x_1} \left|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\right|^{\Delta_2/d}_{x=x_2} \langle\phi_1(x_1')\phi_2(x_2')\rangle.
\end{equation}

Now, from translational and rotational symmetry we have that $$\langle\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\rangle = f(\left| x_1-x_2\right|).$$

By scaling $x$ i.e. letting $x\rightarrow \lambda x$ we get that

\begin{equation}
f(\left| x_1-x_2\right|) = \lambda^{\Delta_1 +\Delta_2}f(\lambda \left| x_1-x_2\right|).
\end{equation}

Now comes the "final" step that I fail to see or understand. Without too much explonation (maybe because it is straight forward, but I still don't se it) they say that this fixes the two point function up to an overall constant:

\begin{equation}
\langle\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\rangle = \frac{C}{|x_1 - x_2|^{\Delta_1 + \Delta_2}}.
\end{equation}

I don't see how letting

\begin{equation}
\langle\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\rangle = f(\left| x_1-x_2\right|) = \lambda^{\Delta_1 +\Delta_2}f(\lambda \left| x_1-x_2\right|)
\end{equation}
tells us that we must have $f(x) \approx \frac{1}{x}$.

If I use this ansatz I get

\begin{equation}
f(\left| x_1-x_2\right|) = \frac{1}{\left| x_1-x_2\right|}= \lambda^{\Delta_1 +\Delta_2} \frac{1}{\lambda \left| x_1-x_2\right|} = \lambda^{\Delta_1 +\Delta_2 -1} \frac{1}{ \left| x_1-x_2\right|}.
\end{equation}

The only way I could see that this is true is if it was known that the sum of the scaling dimensions must always be one i.e. $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 =1$, but I don't know if this is true?

Anyone who see my confusion?

Comment: Shouldn't the scaling property suggest that $f(x)\sim 1/x^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  $f( |x|)= \lambda^\Delta f(\lambda |x|)$ holds for any $\lambda$, take the particular value  $\lambda= |x|^{-1}$. Then the relation becomes
$$
f(|x|)= |x|^{-\Delta}f(1)
$$
Call $f(1)$, "$C$".